# JS use DOM to add content in a table

Tags: javascript

I have the following scenario:
 - I have a div containing 2 inputs (name and phone no) and a button (Add Contact);
 - When I fill the inputs and click Add Contact, I need to create a table with the filled data, adding a new row every time I add a new contact;

Link in comment.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yUfhL/1348/

Answer (score 0):

```
var value1 = $('input[name=Option]').val();
var value2 = $('input[type=number]').val();

var newRow = jQuery('<tr><td>'+value1+'</td><td>'+value2+'</td></tr>');
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Input type `text and numbers` do not have the `:checked` attribute
2. `<input>` does not have closing pair `</input>`

```js
jQuery('.add-content').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    
    var name = $('#name').val();
    var phone = $('#phone').val();
    
    var newRow = jQuery('<tr><td>'+name+'</td><td>'+phone+'</td></tr>');
    jQuery('table').append(newRow);
});
```

```css
.widget {width:35%;padding:20px;background:#ccc;margin:10px;float:left;}
table {background:#ffcc66;margin:10px;}
td {padding:10px;border:2px solid #fff}
thead {background:orange; display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr><td>Nume</td><td>Telefon</td></tr>
    </thead>
</table>

<div class="widget">
    <h2>Phone Book</h2>
       <form id="myForm">
         Name:<input type="text" name="Option" value="test" id="name"><br>
          Phone No:<input type="number" name="Option" value="1" id="phone">
       </form><br>
    <button href="#" title="" class="add-content">Add Contact</button>
</div>
```